# Deploying a Django app that relies on git repository in a secure way

Tags: django, git, deployment, linode

I would like to know what is the "recommended" way to deploy Django apps to a server (Linode, in my case).

I've read several articles about this topic, and I specially liked [this one](http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/deploy.html). But I'm still not convinced. The idea of having a .git file in a production server sounds like risky for me. And even with the recommended way mentioned on that article (git checkout), you have a repository in your production server.

I guess I could use a complex tool like Jenkins or SaltStack to handle the deployment and management of the application, but I am the only developer, and I don't want to invest more time configuring than coding (I'd like to investigate, but I don't really have enough time)

Many thanks in advance

UPDATE: the first comment and first response combined suggest an apparently accepted solution: **Fabric + Jenkins**. And [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mindsocket/towards-continuous-deployment-with-django) talks about it

Comment: Jenkins would be a good choice though. You set it up once and after that you only need to commit and it automatically deploys to the server.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will be my official deployment tool. But I need some time to understand it and put it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed on other SO questions, and I think the consensus is to check out [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) - it's very similar to Capistrano for Rails projects.

Fabric even has [a tutorial for Django](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.0/tutorial.html) - looks promising.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Anyway, I still see the deployment consists in a git pull, or create a tgz and put it in the server root. With the first method, .git files are stored in the prod server (I don't like that). And second method seems inefficient (too much disk writes, even with a few changes in repo), and breaks this rule: "Files that were deleted in the git repo since the last deployment should get deleted from the deployment directory". Maybe fabric + jenkins is a good strategy...